# Test for account partially logged into cloudkit? "Update Apple ID Settings"

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I've got an iOS app that is reliant on cloudkit for much of the functionality.  However, I seem to be able to get in a state where the user is **partially** logged in.  Basic cloudkit login checks pass, I can get my recordID, but I can't read or write to records like I can when I'm fully logged in.

Full details below - any ideas on how to identify this state without testing a read or write?

Upon launch of the phone, I get an 'Update Apple ID Settings' alert that states

> **"Some account services will not be available until you sign in again"**

So, the issue is clearly related to that (which seems to be frequent with the simulator...).  If I got to my settings and re-enter my password, all is well with the world.  I can deal with this by error handling on an attempt to read or write, but I'd rather check in advance and warn the user appropriately.

How I check today:

At launch, I check to see if the user is logged in to cloudkit:

```swift
    if FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil {
        print("User logged in") // IT PASSES IN THIS STATE
    }
    else {
        print("User is not logged in")
    }
```

So far, so good. The test passes, the user is logged in.  However, when I go to read or write, it is clear that I'm NOT logged in.  For example, I'll get a CKErrorPermissionFailure when trying to write.

Additional note - in the current, 'partially'? logged in state, the below returns the correct recordID for my user:

```
let container = CKContainer.default()
container.fetchUserRecordID() { recordID, error in
```

Any ideas on how to programatically identify this partial state for cloudkit?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found an answer that will address this, but wanted to document two things that could be of use

1. While the status check returns active, if I then try to fetch a record that requires you to be logged into iCloud, it fails and I can use that failure to determine logout status.
2. The other issue I've run into is a handful of users that have iCloud turned on but do NOT have iCloud Drive enabled for some reason.  You can check for that with the approach below:

```swift
    CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountstatus, error) in
            switch accountstatus {
                case .noAccount:
                    log.error("user logged out of iCloud OR iCloud Drive off")  
            case .restricted:
                print("restricted")
            case .available:
                print("user logged into iCloud and iCloud drive")  
            case .couldNotDetermine:
                 log.warning("could not determine account status")
            default:
                log.error("New account status returned")
       }
    }
```